# Moodle page Included js file still shows ReferenceError: wordfindgame is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, module, moodle

I am creating a word-search activity type plugin in moodle for my client and trying to use this code into moodle activity type plugin.

Source:https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/274/how-to-create-a-wordfind-game-soup-of-letters-in-the-browser-easily-using-javascript

but the problem is it shows here

> "ReferenceError: wordfindgame is not defined"

```
 ?>
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config.php');
    global $CFG,$PAGE;
    $id = optional_param( 'id', null, PARAM_INT );

    if ($id) {
    if (!$cm = get_coursemodule_from_id('cryptext', $id)) {
    print_error('invalidcoursemodule');
}
if (!$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $cm->course))) {
    print_error('coursemisconf');
}
}

require_login($course, false, $cm);

$PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/mod/cryptext/view.php',array('id' => $cm->id));

$context = context_module::instance($cm->id);

$PAGE->set_title('Cryptext Activity');
$PAGE->set_heading($course->fullname);
$PAGE->set_context($context); //context_system::instance()
//$PAGE->set_context(context_module::instance($id));
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('incourse');

$PAGE->requires->css($CFG->dirroot.'/mod/cryptext/style/wordfind.css');
echo $OUTPUT->header();
 <div id="puzzle-container"></div>
    <div id="puzzle-words"></div>
    <input type="button" id="solveBTN" value="Solve puzzle"/>

     <script>
        // An array with the words to show
        var words = ['cows', 'tracks', 'arrived', 'located', 'sir', 'seat',
           'division', 'effect', 'underline', 'view', 'annual',
           'anniversary', 'centennial', 'millennium', 'perennial',
           'artisan', 'apprentice', 'meteorologist', 'blizzard', 'tornado',
           'intensify','speed','count','consonant','someone',
           'sail','rolled','bear','wonder','smiled','angle', 'absent',
           'decadent', 'excellent', 'frequent', 'impatient', 'cell',
           'cytoplasm', 'organelle', 'diffusion', 'osmosis',
           'respiration'
       ];
        // Start a basic word game without customization !
        var gamePuzzle = wordfindgame.create(words, '#puzzle-container', '#puzzle-words');

        $("#solveBTN").click(function(){
            // Solve the puzzle !
            var result = wordfindgame.solve(gamePuzzle, words);
            console.log(result);
        });        
    </script>
  <?php


  $PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/cryptext/javascript/wordfind.js') );
  $PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/cryptext/javascript/wordfindgame.js') );
  echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

> ReferenceError: wordfindgame is not defined[Learn More]
>   view.php:716:17

I have included the wordfid.js and wordfindgame.js and i went to page source code and clicked the js file link which showed the file content in the browser. It will be very helpful if someone could help me out in solving this issue thanks in prior.

Comment: You need to add the reference to `wordfindgame.js` ***before*** you use it in the JS code. The same too for `wordfind.js`

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
$PAGE->requires->js method accepts second parameter to include file in header. By default second parameter is 'false'. You can send 'true' to include it in header to use it without any conflicts.

Method 2:
You can write your JS code after dependencies ( wordfindgame.js and wordfind.js files in your case) loaded. You can check where it loaded in web page from page source of the browser.